# Algorithm of Bubble sort optimised way

Tags: java, algorithm, bubble-sort

I have  2 different codes for sorting an array:

```java
    static void bubbleSort2(int[] arr){
        System.out.println( "bubble starts ");
        int  tmp =0;int cnt =0;
        for (int i=0; i< arr.length-1 ; i++){
            for (int j=i+1; j< arr.length ; j++){
                if(arr[i] > arr[j]){
                    tmp = arr[j];
                    arr[j]=arr[i];
                    arr[i] = tmp ;
                }
                cnt++;
            }
            printMe(arr);

        }
        System.out.println("Bubble cnt="+cnt);
        printMe(arr);
    }
```

And:

```java
    static void bubbleSort(int a[])
    {
        int len = a.length; 
        int cnt=0;
        System.out.println( "bubble starts ");

        for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < len-i-1; j++) {
                if (a[j] > a[j+1]) 
                {
                    int temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j+1];
                    a[j+1] = temp;
                }
            cnt++;
            }
            printMe(a);
        }
        System.out.println("Bubble cnt="+cnt);
        printMe(a);
    }
```

`bubbleSort2` is written by me, and I find it is printing the `cnt` value more than what the `bubbleSort` function is printing .

Below is the output for array --> `int[] bbArr= { 28,6,4,2,24 };`

```
    bubbleSort(bbArr);
    bubbleSort2(ccArr);
```

```
bubble starts 

    6,4,2,24,28
    4,2,6,24,28
    2,4,6,24,28
    2,4,6,24,28
    Bubble cnt=10

bubble starts 

    2,28,6,4,24
    2,4,28,6,24
    2,4,6,28,24
    2,4,6,24,28
    Bubble cnt=10
```

I see that one method keeps sorting from the starting position, while the  other  method keeps sorting from the last position of array. Does it really matter the order of sorting in a particular sorting algo?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not implementing bubble sort, but a kind of [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

One characteristic of bubble sort is that it only swaps *adjacent* values. Your algorithm swaps values that can be far apart.

You are right that standard bubble sort will grow a sorted partition at the *right* side of the array, while standard selection sort will grow a sorted partition at the *left* side of the array. (Obviously, these algorithms can be made to run in the opposite direction).

> I find it is printing the `cnt` value more than what the `bubbleSort` function is printing.

It is not *more*. Both of your functions execute a predictable number of comparisons which only depends on the *size* of the input array, not on the actual contents: (−1)/2

> Does it really matter the order of sorting in a particular sorting algo ?

When comparing these two algorithms, it doesn't matter. But more importantly though, these two sorting algorithms do not perform well when the input array is large. For relatively large arrays you'll get better run times with sorting algorithms that have an average complexity of O(log), such as quick sort, merge sort, heap sort,...

Comment: Minor nit: the order or sorting *does* matter, even when comparing these two algorithms. With a minor modification, Bubblesort can be made to early out, making the best case O(n). Average and worst case are of course O(n^2). Selection sort, however is *always* O(n^2); there is no potential for early out.

Comment: @Jim, I was considering the code as presented, without any minor modification. The code presented by the asker has a predictable number of comparisons.

Comment: @trincot : the cnt value  mismatch was my mistake in typing the code.  I forgot to add parentheses around inner for loop  .  cnt  value is same for both . thanks for explaining the answer so well.

Comment: Both the  methods are  bubble sort  . unlike to what you said it is selection sort  . in selection sort  inner counter  is one ahead of the  outer counter.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to disagree. Also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) states that Bubble sort constitutes of *"comparing the current element with the one after it"*. Your code is not doing that. Your code is looking at the subarray after the current index of the outer loop to eventually swap the least element into slot `i`. That is a hallmark of selection sort. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) says about it *"The algorithm proceeds by finding the smallest (or largest, depending on sorting order) element in the unsorted sublist"*

Comment: @summary Bubblesort is characterized by the larger elements being swapped (bubbled) towards the end of the array. That's what the code in your `bubbleSort` does, as you can see by the output you provide. Selection sort is characterized by finding the largest item, swapping it to the first, the next largest, swapping it to the second, etc. Which is what your `bubbleSort2` does. The algorithms are vastly different. `bubbleSort2` is not by any definition a bubble sort.